# Compute real roots of a quadratic equation in Pascal

Tags: freepascal, quadratic, equation-solving

I am trying to solve this problem :

(Write a program to compute the real roots of a quadratic equation (ax<sup>2</sup> + bx + c = 0). The roots can be calculated using the following formulae:

x1 = (-b + sqrt(b<sup>2</sup> - 4ac))/2a

and

x2 = (-b - sqrt(b<sup>2</sup> - 4ac))/2a

I wrote the following code, but its not correct:

```
program week7_lab2_a1;
var a,b,c,i:integer;
x,x1,x2:real;

begin
  write('Enter the value of a :');
  readln(a);

  write('Enter the value of b :');
  readln(b);

  write('Enter the value of c :');
  readln(c);

  if (sqr(b)-4*a*c)>=0 then
    begin
      if ((a>0) and (b>0)) then
        begin
          x1:=(-1*b+sqrt(sqr(b)-4*a*c))/2*a;
          x2:=(-1*b-sqrt(sqr(b)-4*a*c))/2*a;

          writeln('x1=',x1:0:2);
          writeln('x2=',x2:0:2);
        end
      else
        if ((a=0) and (b=0)) then
          write('The is no solution')
        else
          if ((a=0) and (b<>0)) then
            begin
              x:=-1*c/b;
              write('The only root :',x:0:2);
            end;
    end
  else
    if (sqr(b)-4*a*c)<0 then
      write('The is no real root');

  readln;
end.
```

do you know why?

and taking a=-6,b=7,c=8 .. can you desk-check it after writing the pesudocode?

Answer (score 2):

You have an operator precedence error here:

```
x1:=(-1*b+sqrt(sqr(b)-4*a*c))/2*a;
x2:=(-1*b-sqrt(sqr(b)-4*a*c))/2*a;
```

See at the end, the `2 * a` doesn't do what you think it does. It does divide the expression by 2, but then *multiplies* it by `a`, because of precedence rules. This is what you want:

```
x1:=(-1*b+sqrt(sqr(b)-4*a*c))/(2*a);
x2:=(-1*b-sqrt(sqr(b)-4*a*c))/(2*a);
```

In fact, this is because the expression is evaluated left-to-right wrt brackets and that multiplication and division [have the same priority](http://www.hkbu.edu.hk/~bba_ism/ISM2110/pas039.htm). So basically, once it's divided by 2, it says "I'm done with division, I will multiply what I have now with `a` as told".

As it doesn't really seem clear from the formula you were given, this is the quadratic formula:

[image]

As you can see you need to divide by 2a, so you must use brackets here to make it work properly, just as the correct text-only expression for this equation is x = (-b +- sqrt(b^2 - 4ac)) / (2a).

---

Otherwise the code looks fine, if somewhat convoluted (for instance, you could discard cases where (a = 0) and (b = 0) right after input, which would simplify the logic a bit later on). Did you really mean to exclude negative coefficients though, or just zero coefficients? You should check that.

Also be careful with floating-point equality comparison - it works fine with 0, but will usually not work with most constants, so use an epsilon instead if you need to check if one value is equal to another (like such: `abs(a - b) < 1e-6`)

Comment: Thanks Tomas. I wanted to exclude the negative value of (sqr(b)-4*a*c). However, even after modifying the 2*a to (2a), there was no output when I tried to run the program by applying a=-6 , b=7 ,c=8. Can you check it man. Thanks again

Comment: @user1592356 that part is fine, I meant the coefficients a, b, c. If you look at your code closely and walk through it, you'll notice that it completely ignores negative values of "a" for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Completely agree with what Thomas said in his answer. Just want to add some optimization marks:

You check the discriminant value in if-statement, and then use it again:

```
if (sqr(b)-4*a*c)>=0 then
...
x1:=(-1*b+sqrt(sqr(b)-4*a*c))/2*a;
x2:=(-1*b-sqrt(sqr(b)-4*a*c))/2*a;
```

This not quite efficient - instead of evaluating discriminant value at once you compute it multiple times. You should first compute discriminant value and store it into some variable:

```
D := sqr(b)-4*a*c;
```

and after that you can use your evaluated value in all expressions, like this:

```
if (D >= 0) then
...
x1:=(-b+sqrt(D)/(2*a);
x2:=(-b-sqrt(D)/(2*a);
```

and so on.

---

Also, I wouldn't write `-1*b`... Instead of this just use `-b` or `0-b` in worst case, but not multiplication. Multiplication here is not needed.

---

**EDIT**:

One more note:

Your code:

```
if (sqr(b)-4*a*c)>=0 then
begin
 ...
end
  else
    if (sqr(b)-4*a*c)<0 then
      write('The is no real root');
```

You here double check the if-condition. I simplify this:

```
if (a) then
    begin ... end
else
    if (not a)
    ...
```

Where you check for `not a` *(in your code it corresponds to `(sqr(b)-4*a*c)<0`)* - in this case condition can be only false (for a) and there is no need to double check it. You should just throw it out.

Comment: @user1592356 Your are welcome, but I said nothing about coefficients :). Ok, about them. You should not check values of them at all (only if is said so in your assignment). Instead you have only and exact 3 situations here: when D > 0 - you have 2 different real roots, when D = 0 - you have exactly one real root (or 2 similar roots), and when D < 0 - you do not have any real roots. Thats all and you do not have a need for checking any coefficients, but only discriminant.